# C# Escaping double quotes with String interpolation in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, interpolation, string-interpolation

I have the following razor code with ternary operator to include or omit a data-* attribute:

```
 <select class="form-control"
        @(field.DependentDropdown ? $"data-selected={Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)}" : "")>
```

When it renders in HTML it comes out like this:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        data-selected="Toyota" yaris="">
```

As you can see the value for the data-selected attribute is not being correctly formatted - it should be one word enclosed in double quotes `"Toyota Yaris"`.

How do I correctly escape or add doubles quotes to:

```
 $"data-selected={Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)}"
```

Comment: What does `Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)` resolve to?

Comment: just do the quotes twice? `""`, or even use a single quote `'` inside the string

Comment: Suggestion: move the ternary operator to a razor c# variable, and use the variable in the html instead. Should be much easier to read and maintain. (Doesn't fix the immediate problem though)

Comment: @maccettura it returns `Toyota Yaris`

Comment: @SeanT already tried `""` and `'` and same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is to use the seldom seen [`<text>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#explicit-delimited-transition) syntax

e.g.

```
<h1 @{if (true) { <text>data-selected="Hello world"</text> } }>Hello</h1>
```

try this:

```
 <select class="form-control"
        @{ if (field.DependentDropdown) { <text>data-selected="@Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)"</text> } }>
```

I'm having a tough time convincing it to work in the ternary operator - feel free to edit answer if you get the syntax right

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the string in a call to the [Raw() method on the HtmlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) class.

```
<select class="form-control"
    @(field.DependentDropdown ? Html.Raw($"data-selected=\"{Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)}\"") : "")>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this.

An example in [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7eriLi)

```
 $"data-selected=\"{Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name)}\""
```

Comment: already tried that and it renders as `data-select="&quot;Toyota" yaris&quot;=""`

Comment: @adam78 that means your result contains spaces,  trim your result before rendering remove the sign `=` at the end

Comment: there are no spaces in results. By using backslashes as per your solution I end up with the following: `data-select=""Toyota" yaris&quot;`. I know there are no spaces becuase when i try `data-selected="@(Model.KeyValues.GetValue(field.Name))"` it renders fine